# jquery / ajax conflict rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I'm currently using rails3 with jquery-plugin

I've been successfully using datepicker in my application however, I've just added some js from railcast 240 for ajax search. In my application.js file, I have the following:

```
$(function() {
  $("#orders th a, #orders .pagination a").live("click", function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
  $("#orders_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#orders_search").attr("action"), $("#orders_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });

$("#order_installationdate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
  $("#order_orderdate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
  $("#milestone_milestone_due").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
  $("#milestone_milestone_completed").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
  $("#task_dueddate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
  });
});
```

However there seems to be a conflict between the two. I can have either or but not both together.

Answer (score 2):

There's a syntax error on the second-to-last line in your JS.  There's a `});` on a line by itself that doesn't appear to match anything.

Your indentation is a bit messed up, so it's not too easy to spot.

Comment: Hi. taking that out, the first function now works but date picker's not playing. Would it be best to separate them?

Comment: The best thing I can suggest, is using the JavaScript console on your browser to see what the errors are (if any).  In Chrome you go View -> Developer -> JavaScript Console.  Safari has the same thing, but I forget which menu it lives under.  In Firefox you'll want to install the Firebug plugin.